# LINQ function to return list but compiler says function doesn't return a value on all code path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, list

Here is my code

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function getlocationsbypro(searchtype As String, crime As String, proid As String, startdate As String, enddate As String, starttime As String, endtime As String) As List(Of crimelocation)

    If searchtype = "withdatetime" Then
        Dim locs As New crimemsapslocationDataContext
        Dim giveloc = From locations In locs.crimelocations _
                      Where locations.INCIDENTTYPE = crime And (locations.DATE_COMTD >= Convert.ToDateTime(startdate) And locations.DATE_COMTD <= Convert.ToDateTime(enddate)) _
                      And (locations.gettimecom >= starttime And locations.gettimecom <= endtime) _
                      Select locations
        Return giveloc.ToList
    ElseIf searchtype = "withdate" Then
        Dim locs As New crimemsapslocationDataContext
        Dim giveloc = From locations In locs.crimelocations _
                      Where locations.INCIDENTTYPE = crime And (locations.DATE_COMTD >= Convert.ToDateTime(startdate) And locations.DATE_COMTD <= Convert.ToDateTime(enddate)) _
                      Select locations

        Return giveloc.ToList
    ElseIf searchtype = "without" Then
        Dim locs As New crimemsapslocationDataContext
        Dim giveloc = From locations In locs.crimelocations _
                      Where locations.INCIDENTTYPE = crime _
                      Select locations

        Return giveloc.ToList
    End If

End Function
```

but when I compile it says that the function doesn't return a value on all code path despite having a return statement on all of my if statement am I missing something and also I notice when there if no elseif statement just the usual if else end it doesn't give me an error stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All code paths don't return a value.

```
 If searchtype = "withdatetime" Then
        Dim locs As New crimemsapslocationDataContext
        Dim giveloc = From locations In locs.crimelocations _
                      Where locations.INCIDENTTYPE = crime And (locations.DATE_COMTD >= Convert.ToDateTime(startdate) And locations.DATE_COMTD <= Convert.ToDateTime(enddate)) _
                      And (locations.gettimecom >= starttime And locations.gettimecom <= endtime) _
                      Select locations
        Return giveloc.ToList
    ElseIf searchtype = "withdate" Then
        Dim locs As New crimemsapslocationDataContext
        Dim giveloc = From locations In locs.crimelocations _
                      Where locations.INCIDENTTYPE = crime And (locations.DATE_COMTD >= Convert.ToDateTime(startdate) And locations.DATE_COMTD <= Convert.ToDateTime(enddate)) _
                      Select locations

        Return giveloc.ToList
    ElseIf searchtype = "without" Then
        Dim locs As New crimemsapslocationDataContext
        Dim giveloc = From locations In locs.crimelocations _
                      Where locations.INCIDENTTYPE = crime _
                      Select locations

        Return giveloc.ToList
    End If
 // if none of the if-else conditions are met your code goes straight to here and there is not return statement
    Return null; // this fixes it.
```

You could also just put an `else` at the end of the if-else which would probably be better. I didn't notice the ElseIf's at fist cause I don't write that VB stuff.

Comment: yes! i should put an else statement on the last line?is that what you are saying?

Comment: @user2334366 you can either put a return statement outside of it (where I have it in the code sample) or you can add an `Else` to the end and put it there. Works either way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have another Return statement after End If. Otherwise, your code will not return anything if none of the If or ElseIf conditions are satisfied.

Comment: thanks for the speedy answer guys yeah i forgot the else statement which evanmcdonnal says its better